# I accidentally used xkill on my desktop - how can I get it back?

Tags: command-line, icons, xkill

I ran `xkill` to force quit Chrome, and I clicked my desktop. The icons disappeared.

Is there a command that will get them back? I'd rather not restart.

I'm using GNOME and GDM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The desktop icons are managed by file browser, on regular running try

```
$ ps ax | grep nautilus
 2464 ?        Sl     0:11 nautilus -n
 6390 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto nautilus
```

From `man nautilus`

```
   -n
   --no-default-window
          Only create windows for explicitly specified URIs.
```

In this mode `nautilus` will not show a window, and it run like a daemon. So for you case use:

```
nautilus -n & disown
```

Comment: In Unity instead of Gnome Desktop, it also works without the `-n` flag and opening a normal Nautilus window just starts the separate daemon in background as well.

Answer (score 9):

It turns out this can be fixed with Gnome Tweak Tool.

Using `xkill` on the desktop sometimes turns off the "Icons on Desktop" setting:

Turning this back on fixed it:

[image]
[image]

If the setting is not turned off, then just turning it off and on again brings them back.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Wut ? `xkill` toggles show icons settings ? That's quite weird. Desktop should be managed by file browser not `gsettings` . . . Or maybe Gnome is just werid

Comment: @Serg I guess it's weird :p

Comment: @Serg, this should work too, as all it does it stops `nautilus -n` which is running in the background when off, and launch it if is on. this handled by `gnome-settings-daemon` or `unity-settings-daemon`.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is open Nautilus and all will be back.

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: I don't know how this is on Gnome, but simply launching **Nautilus** from the launcher or `nautilus & disown` from the terminal solves this problem perfectly well on Unity! @Sneetsher and @Tim

Comment: @ByteCommander , Excuse me Doug you deserve my up vote. I judged your answer on my own experience using an older release, However *I confirm that your answer work as supposed  on **Ubuntu 15.10  for both Unity & Gnome Shell***. Thank you ByteCommander for correcting me.

Comment: @Tim , Could you please review this because it seems to depend on the release. If you can mention here in a comment in which release did not work for you. It will be helpful for other users as the question is not for specific release, I think it does not deserve a down vote at least .

Comment: @sne the question says gnome, do you mean version?

Comment: @tim yes i mean the gnome version

Comment: @Sneetsher I don't know that. I think this *does* deserve my downvote because this didn't work for me... If you hover over the downvote it says "This answer is not useful" - well, for me, it isn't.

Comment: @Tim yes i agree, it is ok, but could you please let me know your version of Gnome?

Comment: @Sneetsher At college right now, and I'm not sure. Will try to find out at home later (around 6 pm UTC)

Comment: @Tim it depends on whether you are using nautilus to draw the desktop. In any case, this is basically the same as the answer you accepted and also what your answer is doing in the background.

Comment: @terdon all I know is this didn't get the icons back.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers did not work for me, but this command does for Kubuntu 18.04

```
kstart plasmashell
```

I hope this could helps others!